# Any good strategy to keep cached content up to date in progressive web app?

Tags: caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am reading an article about service worker from google.

In the chapter "Cache and return requests", it demonstrates a cache first approach:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(response) {
        // Cache hit - return response
        if (response) {
          return response;
        }
        return fetch(event.request);
      }
    )
  );
});
```

It immediately response when hitting cache, but what if the response has been changed after it cached? As far as I know, `CacheStorage` is not like cookie, it don’t expire unless deleted.

Is there any good strategy to keep cache up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Service workers and the Cache API are used to cache *static* assets not data; therefore the response is unlikely to have changed unless there was some form of a deployment. In which case you would inform the service worker to download the next version of the static files (by invalidating the cache by updating the cache name; for example through a gulp process...etc). Or you could use [sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache) which does this work (and more) for you.

On the other hand, if you are caching data, you would use something similar to IndexedDB and once you have an active connection you would download the latest version of the data.

Read more: https://medium.com/dev-channel/offline-storage-for-progressive-web-apps-70d52695513c#.m7k9smyv6